# Load Multiple Separate Swift Files into Main Container View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, xcode7

Ok, so I will apologize in advance, but I am a complete noob to Swift and iOS development, but I really want to learn to code. I have followed quite a few tutorials and so forth online, but cannot seem to find an answer for this problem I am having. There has to be a simple solution to this because it doesn't seem like a very hard issue but the googles are not being my friend in finding an answer. I do not want to use storyboards because I want to learn the real meat and potatoes. I am using OS X 10.11, Xcode 7, writing the app for iOS 9, universal.

So, I designed a calendar app with quite a unique display, UI, and functionality than the other grid based calendars out there. I have a UIView that I want to be a container to hold the other views I need and pull them into the container view. The files I have are the included ViewController.swift and my custom files ContainerView.swift HeaderView.swift, CalView.swift, and CalDetailView.swift. I set classes for each file, the HeaderView is a basic UIView, CalView is a horizontal UIScrollView that enables pagination for the different calendar views like week, month, day, year, and so on. The CalDetailView is also a horizontal UIScrollView that will display event details to the user and also be the primary action area for the user for editing, adding events, etc.

Currently the ContainerView loads just fine and I can do whatever I want there and can create these other subviews without a problem but only in the ContainerView file. I want to keep these areas separated out into different files for my sanity and add them into ContainerView UIView as subViews with AutoLayout and everything, just like I am able to do inside the ContainerView file, but it would be enormous and I don't want that.

I believe the proper way to do this is to add these subViews under the viewDidLoad() method of the main VC and create my AutoLayout constraints in the VC file, then I just want to load my subViews in the ContainerView file and build the screen. The separate subView files will contain all of my drawing code and touch events and so forth for the views.

Here's a simple wireframe of what I am trying to accomplish...
The whole window is ContainerView.swift the rest, subViews of ContainerView.

[WireFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhUpv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a little open ended and non specific, but let's ignore this for now (it is your first time), in future please be more specific, this is the kind of response a tutorial might be better providing. You will have enough to do, without avoiding Storyboards - feel free to use them.

In any case it is fine.

Given a UIView subclass MyView, in your main view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ....
    let myView = MyView()
    self.view.addSubView(myView)
    myView.frame = ... OR <SET CONSTRAINTS>
    ....
}
```

Essentially you will initialise those view subclasses and add them as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for going easy on the noobie, I do appreciate it. I tried to be as specific as I could. Unfortunately, this did not work. I added the code suggested, but got an error on the line self.addSubView which read "Value of Type ViewController has no member named addSubview." I looked it up in the Apple docs and its only a member of UIView. I tried adding it there, no dice. I didn't receive the error and it built fine, but the view doesn't display.

Comment: Thank you. I no longer get the error and it builds fine, but the view isn't visible. I dug around Apple's documentation to try to find a solution as to why it isn't visible and thought that it wasn't layered properly. So I added the bringSubviewToFront() method, no dice. Then i figured that it wasn't initialized properly, so I followed Apple's init method of initializing the view, and it still does not display. When I take my drawing code out and place it into the VC, no problem. Also when I place it into the ContainerView file, it also displays. It seems to not know it's there, but no errors.

Comment: Ok, got it figured out. I didn't make my bounds in the VC file as they were there for in the views files. I moved my constraints over the VC file, kept my drawing code in the separate view files and it works perfectly. Now, figuring out the quirks of Auto Layout... fun stuff. Thanks Mitchell, I really appreciate your help.